# Java/Android: Return a class name through a method

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance

I'm trying to make a base class fragmentstatepageradapter and I want the getItem method to return a new fragment instance, but I want that fragment to be of any possible child type. I figured it would be something like this, but it's throwing an error:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem( int position ) {

    if( mRosterUids == null || mRosterUids.size() <= position )
        return null;
    Log.e( "RosterDetailsPagerAdapter", "getItem(): " + mRosterUids.get(position) );
    return getItemClass().newInstance(mRosterUids.get(position));
}

public java.lang.Class<SLRosterDetailsFragment> getItemClass() {
    return SLRosterDetailsFragment.class;
}
```

The error message is from mRosterUids.get(position) inside of newInstance, and it says

"newInstance() in Class cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)"

and the working version that isn't very flexible is:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem( int position ) {

    if( mRosterUids == null || mRosterUids.size() <= position )
        return null;
    Log.e( "RosterDetailsPagerAdapter", "getItem(): " + mRosterUids.get(position) );
    return SLRosterDetailsFragment.newInstance(mRosterUids.get(position));
}
```

Is this possible to get working, or should I simply have my child functions override getItem to return their own fragments.

Comment: The first solution smells of needless hack imho, not to mention Reflection is slow and could impact your UX in the long run.

Comment: This is just a guess, but the Java String class is immutable which may explain the error. Have you tried this code on other classes? Mutable and immutable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, folks. I'm pretty green in software engineering (junior dev, first job), so was just playing with the idea to see if I could make my adapter more extensible and easier to work with later. After reading the comments and playing with some things, it occurred to me that there's a much simpler way to go about this...

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem( int position ) {

    if( mRosterUids == null || mRosterUids.size() <= position )
        return null;
    Log.e( "RosterDetailsPagerAdapter", "getItem(): " + mRosterUids.get(position) );
    return getRosterDetailsFragment( mRosterUids.get(position) );
}

public SLRosterDetailsFragment getRosterDetailsFragment( String uid ) {
    return SLRosterDetailsFragment.newInstance( uid );
}
```

and I'm sure I could even turn the return type to Fragment, but eh. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Change your getItemClass() to

```
public <T extends Object> T getItemClass() {
    return SLRosterDetailsFragment.class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are indirectly executing:

`return SLRosterDetailsFragment.class.newInstance(mRosterUids.get(position));`,

Where you are executing the method `newInstance()` from the class `java.lang.Class` which you derived from `SLRosterDetailsFragment.class` and are 2 completely different objects.

while in the 'working' version it is executing:

`return SLRosterDetailsFragment.newInstance(mRosterUids.get(position));`

Where the class `SLRosterDetailsFragment` has a method called `newInstance`

Which are 2 different methods...